# fix a cell value in excel after its been calculated by a formula

Tags: excel, circular-reference, formulas

I have a bit of a circular reference going:-

A1 = Payment amount
B1 = Number of Payments: Created by counting dates payments made
C1 = Commission due in May (A1 x %age depending on B1)
D1 = Commission due in June (A1 x %age depending on B1)

If B1 = 1  % = 100%.
If B1 = 2, % = 50%.

This works

However C1 needs to stay at 100% once the formula has generated it.  Currently its altering when D1 is then updated (both C1 and D1 read A1 x 50%).

Please Advise.

Comment: Do you want anytime there is a value in `C1` for the to remain static? I don't understand why `D1` alters `C1` if `C1` is referenced to `A1` and `B1`? This can be accomplished but I don't understand your current set up enough to help. What is the trigger that tells you the value in C1 is the value it needs to be locked at? Is it anytime a cell in `C1` is changed and not blank?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, you can't have it both ways. A cell either contains a defined value or a calculated value! You have to rethink your layout or redefine your problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in no way an expert in Excel, but I use it to test my knowledge of vocab. I have to generate a random number that triggers the English test word and the I enter the German equivalent. I have to freeze the random number long enough for the entry and the comparison to occur and I use a circular reference formula in CELL D10: =IF(G10="",RANDBETWEEN(1,G12),D10). 
G10 is the student response cell, and I'm able to hold the question word steady until the English to German comparison is performed and the messages for congratulations/or the correct answer is generated.
Is this any use to you?
Cheers,
George